# c void function invoking an OpenCL functions would not renewed value

Tags: c, opencl

I am writing a void function to get the number of OpenCL devices and the list of OpenCL devices. These two look correct inside the function, but I do not get the correct values inside my main function.

Below is the base minimum code to generate the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CL_TARGET_OPPENCL_VERSION 200
#include <CL/cl.h>


void getcldeviceinfo(int plfn, int dev_type, cl_uint ndev, cl_device_id devs[])
{  
   cl_int         cle;
   cl_uint        nplf;
   cl_platform_id plfs[2];

   // getting the number of platforms and platform ids
   cle   =  clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &nplf);
   cle   =  clGetPlatformIDs(nplf, plfs, NULL);

   if (cle != CL_SUCCESS || nplf <= 0)
   {
      printf("Failed to find any OpenCL platforms\n");
   }


   // getting the number of devices and device ids
   // you need to specify which platform you wish to use
   if (dev_type != 0)
   {
      cle   =  clGetDeviceIDs(plfs[plfn], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, NULL, &ndev);
      cle   =  clGetDeviceIDs(plfs[plfn], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, ndev, devs, NULL);
   }
   else
   {
      cle   =  clGetDeviceIDs(plfs[plfn], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &ndev);
      cle   =  clGetDeviceIDs(plfs[plfn], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, ndev, devs, NULL);
   }


   printf("number of devices inside the function : %u\n",ndev);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cl_device_id devices[10];
    cl_uint ndev = 0;

    printf("number of devices inside the main function before : %u\n",ndev);
    getcldeviceinfo(0, 0, ndev, devices);

    printf("number of devices inside the main function after  : %u\n",ndev);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code above, I expect to get the following output.

```
number of devices inside the main function before : 0
number of devices inside the function : 2
number of devices inside the main function after  : 2
```

but I get

```
number of devices inside the main function before : 0
number of devices inside the function : 2
number of devices inside the main function after  : 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to pass in ndev as a pointer to your function clgetdeviceinfo.

Comment: like getcldeviceinfo(0, 0, &ndev, devices); ?

Comment: Yes but then you will need to adjust your function signature and architecture of the function accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the function parameter `ndev` as call-by reference (the function can then access the memory location where the original `ndev` is stored), not call-by-value (the function makes its own, private copy of `ndev` and cannot modity the original value):

```c
void getcldeviceinfo(int plfn, int dev_type, cl_uint& ndev, cl_device_id* devs) { // note the "&"
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cl_device_id devices[10];
    cl_uint ndev = 0;

    printf("number of devices inside the main function before : %u\n",ndev);
    getcldeviceinfo(0, 0, ndev, devices);

    printf("number of devices inside the main function after  : %u\n",ndev);

    return 0;
}
```

---

For an easy start with OpenCL, I created a lightweight wrapper that vastly simplifies the OpenCL C++ bindings and eliminates the entire code overhead that comes with it. You can get the list of all available devices with `get_devices()` and automatically find the fastest device with `select_device_with_most_flops()`. https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper